# PDF's, Videos, Jpgs that are not a part of the war file on the server

Tags: pdf, websphere

I am developing a STRUTS 2 based web app. I have a large number of pdf's, videos, that cannot be a part of the war file but have to be on a separate location on our websphere server. What is the best way to configure the location in my app?

For example , i will have my pdf's on d:/pdfs/abc.pdf and i want to open it from my jsp as links.

-- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a web server in front of WebSphere? If so, I'd hardcode the JSP links to use paths that you "alias" in your web server. So, like `/pdfs/abc.pdf` where `/pdfs` is a web server alias to `d:/pdfs`.

Comment: yes we are using ibm http server in front of websphere. I went ahead and mapped the alias as /pdfs/ as d:/pdfs/ in the httpd.conf file but its not working :( ... any debugging tips?

Comment: That definitely works. So you have like `Alias /pdfs d:\pdfs`, you restarted IHS, and when you hit `http://server/pdfs/abc.pdf` you get, what, a 404 error? Check the IHS access_log and error_log for the detailed error message.

Comment: The logs state that there is a 404 error. Does my application context which is / in my case have anything to do with it?

Comment: Yes. If WAS owns /, everything will be handled by it by default. If you don't need WAS to serve any static content at all, you can disable "file serving". http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/cweb_flserv.html